# ReferenceError: bot is not defined in discord bot

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

i'm trying to make a discord bot on repl.it but i can't open it this is what it saying:

```
Promise { <pending> }
Hint: hit control+c anytime to enter REPL.
(node:125) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
at WebSocketManager.connect (/home/runner/discord-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:133:26)
at Client.login (/home/runner/discord-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:223:21)
Promise { <pending> }
Hint: hit control+c anytime to enter REPL.
Your Bot is now Online.
/home/runner/discord-bot/index.js:16
setInterval(() => bot.user.setActivity(`${activities[i++ %  activities.length]}`,  {type:"STREAMING",url:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWcJFNfaw9c"  }), 5000)
                                 ^
    
ReferenceError: bot is not defined
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/runner/discord-bot/index.js:16:30)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

and that's my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = 'xxx ';
    
var http = require('http');  
http.createServer(function (req, res) {   
    res.write("I'm alive");   
    res.end(); 
}).listen(8080);
    
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Your Bot is now Online.')
    let activities = [`gang shit`, `with the gang`, `with the gang`   ],i = 0;
    setInterval(() => bot.user.setActivity(`${activities[i++ %  activities.length]}`,  {type:"STREAMING",url:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWcJFNfaw9c"  }), 5000)
});
    
client.on('message', message =>{
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong!')
    }
}); 
    
client.login('my-token');
```

don't worry i regenerated the token.
Please help me it's my first bot and i don't know if i doing this right if you have something to suggest please say it.

Answer (score 1):

Your client is defined as `client`. (`const client = new Discord.Client();`)

You will simply have to change it from saying `bot.user.setActivity()` to `client.user.setActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `bot` into `client`, as you defined `client` and not `bot`.

```js
setInterval(() => client.user.setActivity(`${activities[Math.floor(Math.random() * activities.length)]}`,  {type:"STREAMING",url:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWcJFNfaw9c"  }), 5000)
```

Also you want to get a random index of your `activities` array. That is done by using `activities[Math.floor(Math.random() * activities.length)]`.

Edit:
Your code should look like this now:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = 'xxx ';

var http = require('http');  
http.createServer(function (req, res) {   
  res.write("I'm alive");   
  res.end(); 
}).listen(8080);

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Your Bot is now Online.')
  let activities = [`gang shit`, `with the gang`, `with the gang`];
  setInterval(() => client.user.setActivity(`${activities[Math.floor(Math.random() * activities.length)]}`,  {type:"STREAMING",url:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWcJFNfaw9c"  }), 5000)
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong!')
 }
}); 

client.login('Your Token');
```

Also make sure to use a **valid** token!

Comment: thanks you and sorry for answering in my own question